# NullPointerException: findViewById returns null in Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I´m trying to show a video in a dialog but the VideoView can´t be found, although the id is correct. I get a NullPointerException in this line:

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview1);
```

This is my code:

```
                Dialog dialog2 = new Dialog(getContext(),
                    android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
            dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.video);

            VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview1);
            String uri = "android.resource://" + theGameActivity.getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.video6;
dialog2.show();
            vv.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

Change this..

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview1);
```

to

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.videoview1);
```

Because `View` must refer `Dialog`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview1);
```

to

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView)dialog2.findViewById(R.id.videoview1);
```

because `videoview1` is part of `R.layout.video` and `dialog2` view layout is `R.layout.video`

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.videoview1);
```

you need to use dialog object. specifier to get video view id